# Lodash with typescript find not working with overload

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I am trying to use _.find on typescript on a Object to return a value f this object.
It originally looked like this:

```js
  const iconDict = {
    dashboard: <DataVisualizer />,
    settings: <SettingsApp />,
    'company-manager': <CompanyManager />,
    'tenant-administrator': <TenantAdministrator />,
    glob
  const icon =
    _.find(iconDict, (icon, key) => {
      const url = window.location.href
      if (url.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        return icon
      }
    }) || iconDict['global']
```

The code above gives me the error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(icon: Element, key: string) => Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | symbol | [string | number | symbol, any] | ObjectIterator | PartialShallow | undefined'.
      Type '(icon: Element, key: string) => Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ObjectIterator'.
        Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'
```

Probably because it is falling on [this overload](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts#L378)

I tried to add the typing of the object like this

```js
  const icon =
    _.find<typeof iconDict, JSX.Element>(iconDict, (icon, key) => {
      const url = window.location.href
      if (url.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
        return icon
      }
```

And I then get:

```
Argument of type '(icon: Element, key: string) => Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectIteratorTypeGuard'.
  Signature '(icon: Element, key: string): Element | undefined' must be a type predicate.ts(2345)
```

Because it falls on [this definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts#L369)

And now I am not sure how to proceed. 
How to make the typescript knows that I will return either a type of a value of the object or undefined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are using `@types/lodash`, but it is a first step here, to give TS some signatures of `find`.

There is this override of find:

```js
find<T>(
  collection: List<T> | null | undefined,
  predicate?: ListIterateeCustom<T, boolean>,
  fromIndex?: number
): T|undefined;
```

That should work if you change your predicate to

```js
(icon, key) => {
  const url = window.location.href
  return url.indexOf(key) !== -1 ? icon : false
}
```

So it will return `boolean` in not-found case.